# Is it possible to declare and manipulate a variable (non-element) in a Angular 2 template?

Tags: templates, typescript, angular

For example, I have a set of inputs and I want to set the 'tab'attribute on them, incrementing down the page.  I don't want to say the exact tab number, because I may edit the template later and insert a new input and I don't want to redo every number.

```
<input [attr.tab]="1" />
<input [attr.tab]="2" />
<input [attr.tab]="3" />
```

So I'd rather use a variable *local to the template*, as using a component function generates errors ('Expression '...' has changed after it was checked.')

There are such localized variables in directives like *ngFor, so is it possible to do the same in a component template?  Or a way to achieve this effect generally (ie. not just to forms or something)?

Like:

```
<input [attr.tab]="let i = 1, i" />
<input [attr.tab]="i++" />
<input [attr.tab]="i++" />
```

Template Syntax Doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Edit: Not using *ngFor or any template loop, I'm not trying to specify a inner template.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input [attr.tab]="'1'" #tab1 />
<input [attr.tab]="tab1.getAttribute('tab') + 1" />
<input [attr.tab]="tab1.getAttribute('tab') + 2" />
```

See also this open issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451

Comment: Clever idea, but unfortunately it still requires me to write a unique expression for each one (' + 1','+ 2', etc) which doesn't allow easy code maintenance.  Maybe this method can lead to a solution though.  The open issue is very helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: If you need this a lot I think it should be possible to create a helper directive that allows to do this in a more concise way.